RVC-Project: Unable to start web-interface (Mac OS)
Good daytime. I tried to make a voice2voice AI cover, but am stuck here:
Following the guideline, I run shell script in  Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI
Public directory, but instead of starting web server, it tries to download voce models:
❯ sh ./run.sh
 Activate venv...
 working dir is /Users/inok_Roman/Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI
 downloading requirement aria2 check.
 aria2 command found
 dir check start.
 dir ./assets/pretrained checked
 dir ./assets/pretrained_v2 checked
 dir ./assets/uvr5_weights checked
 dir ./assets/uvr5_weights/onnx_dereverb_By_FoxJoy checked
 dir check finished.
 required files check start.
 checking D32k.pth
 D32k.pth in ./assets/pretrained checked.
 checking D40k.pth
 D40k.pth in ./assets/pretrained checked.
 checking D48k.pth
 D48k.pth in ./assets/pretrained checked.
 checking G32k.pth
 G32k.pth in ./assets/pretrained checked.
 checking G40k.pth
 G40k.pth in ./assets/pretrained checked.
 checking G48k.pth
 G48k.pth in ./assets/pretrained checked.
 checking f0D40k.pth
 f0D40k.pth in ./assets/pretrained_v2 checked.
 checking f0G40k.pth
 failed. starting download from huggingface.
 [#505f88 69MiB/69MiB(99%) CN:1 DL:11MiB]
 Download results:
 gid |stat|avg speed |path/URI
 ======+====+==========+============ ============================================
 505f88|OK | 10MiB/s|./assets/pretrained_v2/f0G40k.pth

 Symbols used:
 (OK): Download complete.
 download successful.

Moreover, it failes. And even when script successefully downloads model f0G40k, it keeps complaining that does not have that the file ( "checking f0G40k.pth \n failed").
Flags such as ./run.sh -help or --help are not working too - script ingnores them and keeps downloading this useless file.

You might want to try this PR: https://github.com/RVC-Project/Retrieval-based-Voice-Conversion-WebUI/pull/2175

@RichardBarber, Thank you! I've fixed dlmodels.sh; Everything works!
